# What dependency is DataSet within?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to connect to the database.  I have the following loaded at the top of my page:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Here is my DataSet code:

```
DataSet Data = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command))
{
    DataAdapter.Fill(Data);
}
```

And my project.json:

```
{
  "webroot":  "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

It doesn't underline my DataSet but when I try to build it returns the error:

> The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I assume the assembly reference is talking about my dependencies.  So what dependency do I need to have access to DataSet?  I looked online and only found people listing things like .dll files without version numbers.  As you can see from my dependencies I don't see a place where I can list a file and a version is required.

Comment: can you share design page might be some directive's missing

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core are you using? RC1 or RC2? Also It could be helpful to post your full project.json. (Looking at dependencies it seems like your using RC1 but why are you mixing RC1 packages with beta-8 ones?)

Comment: You should first update all dependencies to RC1 version. Mixing RC packages with Beta packages can cause serious bugs.

Comment: Thank you VSG24, I've added my full project.json file.

Comment: I don't see RC1 versions available for some of the packages though, thus I was using whatever was on the top of the list, which was beta8

Comment: @Samir Why don't you try removing some of the dependencies you don't need and see how it goes, comment out your existing code if it uses them maybe?

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Comment: Ok I took everything out that was not rc1-final.  I am still getting that same DataSet error.  It is also saying the same thing for SqlDataAdapter as well.  That's not new, it's been saying that from the beginning.

Comment: If I were you, I would start a new RC2 project and then try to use DataSet there.

Comment: The norm for new projects in C# is RC2 I suppose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113979/discussion-between-samir-and-vsg24).

Answer (score 1):

Dataset is under namespace System.Data [System.Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx)
So to use it you must add reference to `System.Data` assembly.

Usually it is packaged together with the installed .Net framework.
So if you are using VS follow this steps to add :

1. In your project root, right click `References`
2. Click `Add Reference`
3. In the popup, under Assemblies section, choose framework
4. Lastly, find and check System.Data assembly

Comment: This is `.Net Core`, no need to add reference.

Comment: @VSG24 sometimes you need to reference it explicitly ithink

Comment: That did not seem to help.  Most tutorials I read act as though you just add using System.Data and then it works.  So I must be missing a dependency right?

Comment: Did you try to add it using the following steps?

Comment: This is most likely not a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have system.data reference in your project check the connection property of SqlDataAdapter once and pass valid connection and valid command to it.

Comment: It is a valid connection and command.  The SqlDataAdapter is having the same issue as the DataSet where it is saying "The type or namespace name 'SqlDataAdapter' could not be found."  But I am using System.Data as you mentioned.